# Buttons disappear form the GUI Form when i use Text Widget in Tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

When i use Entry Widget in line **"inputs = Entry(row)"** the output form can only take single string, as soon i update the code to use Text Wiget 
**"inputs = Text(row)"** the output form accepts multi line string inputs but the buttons disappear, Please help not sure why the buttons disappear

```
from tkinter import *
fields = 'Section1','Section2'    

def fetch(entries):
   for entry in entries:
      field = entry[0]
      text  = entry[1].get()
      print('%s \n%s\n' % ("\n====================================\n" + field + "\n====================================\n", text))    

def makeform(root, fields):
   entries = []
   for field in fields:
      row = Frame(root)
      labels = Label(row, width=35, text=field, anchor='w')
      inputs = Entry(row) # This is the line where i tried Text Widget
      row.pack(side=TOP, fill=X, padx=15, pady=15)
      labels.pack(side=LEFT)
      inputs.pack(side=RIGHT, expand=YES, fill=X)
      entries.append((field, inputs))
   return entries

if __name__ == '__main__':
   root = Tk()
   root.title('Form')
   entries = makeform(root, fields)
   root.bind('<Return>', (lambda event, e=entries: fetch(e)))
   b1 = Button(root, text='Generate', command=(lambda e=entries: fetch(e)))
   b1.pack(side=LEFT, padx=5, pady=5)
   b2 = Button(root, text='Quit', command=root.quit)
   b2.pack(side=LEFT, padx=5, pady=5)
   root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Unable to reproduce.

Comment: Perhaps provide images on the resulting GUI.

Comment: If the problem is when you use `Text`, then show us code that uses `Text` so we can see what you tried.

Comment: Seems fine to me. You might want to use `inputs = Text(row, height=2)` to restrict the height of the widgets as Text widgets default to much taller than an Entry.

Comment: restricting the height of the Text widgets resolved the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Restricting the height of the Text widgets resolved the issue.

```
inputs = Text(row, height=10)
```